# Travelling Salesman with Priorities

Tags: algorithm, sorting, traveling-salesman

Is there an a version of a TSP algorithm that meets the following constraints?

- Priorities must be inserted in numerical order.
- Priority 0 can be inserted everywhere.

An example could be the following valid route between the nodes A to G ( the numbers are the priorities):

A[1] - B[0] - C[1] - D[0] - E[2] - F[3] - G[0]

In general that could be achieved quite easy with an asymmetric TSP and the following rules applied to the cost matrix:

- Costs between any two nodes is the euclidean distance.
- Costs from big to small priorities are set infinite.
- Costs to a bigger priority node get a penalty added to the euclidean distance.

The problem I am facing is that with this approach it sometimes happens that a route like this will be calculated:

A[1] - B[0] - C[1] - D[0] - F[3] - G[0] - E[2]

He will never take a route directly from priority 3 to 2 but when he adds a zero node in between the route becomes likely because the costs between F-G and G-E are penalty free distance costs.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: If you're writing your own TSP solver, then it's simple enough to keep track of the highest priority seen so far, and ignore any routes to nodes with lower priority.

Comment: Well, I'm not writing my own solver and I think I'm not capable of doing so (at least when it should run reasonably fast). I'm currently trying to use LKH-2 from Keld Helsgaun: http://www.akira.ruc.dk/~keld/research/LKH/

Comment: the cost from 0 priority nodes to other nodes should depend on how high the priority is, to try to priorize always the lower remaining ones. Also this is called hierarchical tsp

Comment: I am already doing so. Eg: from Prio 0 to Prio 1 costs are euclidean distance + lets say 100. From Prio 0 to Prio 2 cost are euclidean distance + in this case 200.